# get element which has onclick

Tags: html, jquery

I have this code part:

```
<div id="test" onclick="nextStep()" data-service="1">
```

This works:

```
function nextStep() {
    console.log( $("#test").data("service") )
}
```

But normally the div element has no id, so I tried this:

```
function nextStep() {
    console.log( $(this).data("service") )
}
```

But this will be log "undefined" instead of "1".
Where is my fault?

```js
function nextStep() {
  console.log( $("#test").data("service") );
  console.log( $(this).data("service") );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" onclick="nextStep()" data-service="1">click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this.

```html
<div id="test" onclick="nextStep(this)" data-service="1">Click Me</div>
```

And JS

```js
function nextStep(x) {
    console.log( $(x).data("service") )
  }
```

You can use any variable instead of `x` .

Answer (score 0):

nextStep() is not getting any parameter passed,as you are binding this to onlclick(). Try like this:

```
function nextStep() {
  console.log( $(event.target).data("service") )
}
```

But if you want to pass parameter, you can do that as well like this:

```
function nextStep(param) {
    console.log( $(param).data("service") )
  }
```

Refrence for understanding the behaviour: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick